# Not sure why this does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="button button1" onclick="toggleClass();">Stay Updated</div>

    <script>
        function toggleClass(){
            if(className == "button button1"){
                    className = "info";
          } else {
                    className = "button button 1";
}

    </script>
```

Trying to change the class of the div on clicking the div.  The div is meant to act like a button which should be replaced by another div class.  This is my coding so far, please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assigning a variable called `className` does not automatically change the class of the div tag.  Do a little research and you will figure it out.

Comment: You might want to check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript). The class name exists in the DOM. You can't change it as if it were local to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code. First, you're missing a closing bracket `}` in your if/else statement. Check your console, <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the error:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError:** Unexpected end of input

Secondly, as noted above in the comments, `className` doesn't automatically exist and doesn't change the classes of the elements. `className` is a property of the DOM object. You'll need to get the clicked element and reference the `className` property to retrieve and set this correctly.

Before you can do that however, you need to get the clicked element. To do this, add the `event` parameter to your inline click handler:

```
onclick="toggleClass(event);"
```

and reference the event object in your function `toggleClass`:

```
function toggleClass(evt) {
```

Use the `target` property of the `event` object to find the clicked element and save it off into a variable:

```
var btn = evt.target;
```

Finally, reference `btn.className` in place of all of the `className` references you have in your function.

**DEMO:**

```js
function toggleClass(evt) {
    var btn = evt.target;
  
    if(btn.className == "button button1") {
        btn.className = "info";
    } else {
        btn.className = "button button1";
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  color: #fff;  
}
div.button.button1 {
  background: blue;
}
div.info {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="button button1" onclick="toggleClass(event);">Stay Updated</div>
```